# add and delete rows dynamically with textboxes using jquery but I want text editor in textbox how to add

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```js
window.jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields_limit = 10; //set limit for maximum input fields
    var x = 1; //initialize counter for text box
    window.jQuery('.add_more_button').click(function(e){ //click event on add more fields button having class add_more_button
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields_limit){ //check conditions
            x++; //counter increment
            window.jQuery('.input_fields_container').append('<div><textarea id="tttt" name="product_name[]"></textarea><a href="#" class="remove_field" style="margin-left:10px;">Remove</a></div>'); //add input field
        }
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "#tttt",
            plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
            ],
            toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
        });
    });  

    window.jQuery('.input_fields_container').on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text links
        e.preventDefault();
        window.jQuery(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    })
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="input_fields_container">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="product_name[]">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary add_more_button">Add More Fields</button>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://coinpedia.org/ico-token/assets/js/tinymce_js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: add description

Comment: try content-editable